# MS Access DAO recordset update not working

Tags: ms-access, recordset

I made a MS Access DB (old XP version) which used to work seamlessy.

I had to add a routine to "move" some data from a table to another, and wrote a function to do this.
The method I always used was to use dynamic recordsets (or dynasets), but this time it doesn't work.
The flow correctly opens dynasets, find and copy data from one recordset to the other, but when .update is done nothing appears in the original table.

I use DAO 3.60.

Here's the (summarized) code:

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim rstDoc As Recordset
Dim rstAdd As Recordset
Dim rstDocEmessi As Recordset
Dim rstAddDocEmessi As Recordset
Dim Incassato As Integer

Set rstDoc = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Documenti", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rstDocEmessi = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TS_DocumentiEmessi", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstAdd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Addebiti", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstAddDocEmessi = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TS_Addebiti_DocumentiEmessi", dbOpenDynaset)

numDoc = Forms!TS_SceltaStampa!IdDocumento

    With rstDocEmessi

            rstDocEmessi.AddNew

            rstDocEmessi!IdDocOriginale = rstDoc!IdDocumento
            rstDocEmessi!Data = rstDoc!Data
            rstDocEmessi![#Fattura] = rstDoc![#Fattura]
            ...
            rstDocEmessi!TS_Opposizione = rstDoc!TS_Opposizione
            rstDocEmessi!TS_DataPagamento = rstDoc!TS_DataPagamento
            rstDocEmessi!IsIncassato = (IIf(Incassato = vbYes, True, False))
            rstDocEmessi!IsImportatoInSospesi = False

            rstDocEmessi.Update
            rstDocEmessi.Close

            ' Copia Addebiti
            If Not (rstAdd.EOF And rstAdd.BOF) Then
                rstAdd.MoveFirst
                Do Until rstAdd.EOF = True
                    If rstAdd!Documento = numDoc Then

                        rstAddDocEmessi.AddNew

                        rstAddDocEmessi!IdAddebito = rstAdd!IdAddebito
                        rstAddDocEmessi!Documento = rstAdd!Documento
                        ...
                        rstAdd!TS_TipoSpesa
                        rstAddDocEmessi!Calcola = rstAdd!Calcola
                        rstAddDocEmessi!Totale = rstAdd!Totale

                        rstAddDocEmessi.Update
                    End If
                    rstAdd.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If
            rstAddDocEmessi.Close
            rstAdd.Close
            TS_Registra = True`
```

Comment: Why are you moving records? Could possibly use an INSERT SELECT sql action statement instead of manipulating recordsets.

Comment: Apart to the approach (recordset vs sql) do you see something wrong in my syntax? By the way, I agree with you and I'm used to use SQL in other environments (PHP <-> MySQL) but in Access using the recordset way usually gave me more control over what was happening, especially in debug situations...

Comment: Is Documenti a query that filters to a single record? Incassato is declared but not set. Don't see anything wrong with the recordsets manipulation.

Comment: @Versatile: Did you get a resolution to your problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions.

Firstly don't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you are expecting a particular error in a line of code that you are going to explicitly test for and handle in the very next line of code (by testing `If Err.Number = ...`). You should have an error handling code block and use `On Error GoTo ERROR_CODE_BLOCK`. If you *are* going to turn off the error handler for one particular command then you should turn it back on again straight after you've handled the expected error.

Because you've turned off error handling, it could be that your insert statements are failing due to some constraint violation but you're just not seeing this. For error handling I would recommend structuring your code like this:

```
On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Dim rstDoc As Recordset
    '...
    'insert the body of your Procedure here
    '...

PROC_EXIT:
    'Add any tidying up code that always needs to run. For example, release all your Object variables
    Set rstDoc = Nothing
    Set rstAdd = Nothing
    Set rstDocEmessi = Nothing
    Set rstAddDocEmessi = Nothing
    Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume PROC_EXIT

End Sub
```

General code tidying suggestions.

The `With rstDocEmessi` construct is used to save you a bit of typing. There should be an associated `End With` somewhere in your code, but I don't see this. I would change this bit of code as follows:

```
With rstDocEmessi
    .AddNew
        !IdDocOriginale = rstDoc!IdDocumento
        !Data = rstDoc!Data
        ![#Fattura] = rstDoc![#Fattura]
        ...
        !TS_Opposizione = rstDoc!TS_Opposizione
        !TS_DataPagamento = rstDoc!TS_DataPagamento
        !IsIncassato = (IIf(Incassato = vbYes, True, False))
        !IsImportatoInSospesi = False
    .Update
    .Close
End With
```

Finally, the inserts into `rstAddDocEmessi` could be cleaned up a bit. Rather than opening the whole table of records for `rstAdd` and then checking each record in turn to see if you need to add a `rstAddDocEmessi` record, why not just get the relevant records in your `rstAdd` recordset?

```
Set rstAdd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Addebiti " & _
        "Where Documento = " & Forms!TS_SceltaStampa!IdDocumento, dbOpenDynaset)

'No need to test for (rstAdd.BOF And rstAdd.EOF), and no need for rstAdd.MoveFirst
'Just go straight into...
Do Until rstAdd.EOF = True
    rstAddDocEmessi.AddNew
        rstAddDocEmessi!IdAddebito = rstAdd!IdAddebito
        rstAddDocEmessi!Documento = rstAdd!Documento
        ...
        rstAddDocEmessi!Calcola = rstAdd!Calcola
        rstAddDocEmessi!Totale = rstAdd!Totale
    rstAddDocEmessi.Update
    rstAdd.MoveNext
Loop
```